# Ember model and route setup

Tags: ember.js

Trying to learn Ember with a simple app, which is just a questionnaire.  On the first page of the questionnaire (`localhost:4200/animal`) they choose their favourite animal from a select box (which is a component I made, that I would like to re-use on other questions).  The select box is populated via a RESTful API.

```
//routes/animal.js
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Route.extend({
   model(){
      return this.get('store').findAll('animal');
   }
});


//models/animal.js
export default Model.extend({
   name: attr()
});


//templates/animal.hbs
Choose your favourite animal:
{{select-box
    items=model
    selectedValue=???
}}
{{#link-to "xyz"}}Go to next question{{/link-to}}


//components/select-box/template.hbs
<select {{action 'actionOnChange' on 'change'}} class='{{class}}'>
  {{#each items as |item|}}
    <option value='{{item.id}}' selected={{eq item.id selectedValue}}>{{item.name}}</option>
  {{/each}}
</select>


//components/select-box/component.js
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    selectedValue: '',

    //when load the page, prepopulate the value
    init(){
        this._super(...arguments);
        //retrieve it from somewhere?
        //this.get('selectedValue') is blank if come back to the page
    },

    actions: {
        actionOnChange(){
            //save it somewhere?  where?
            this.set('selectedValue', this.$('select').val());
        }
    }
});
```

If I choose an animal, then go onto the next page of the questionnaire, and then come back to the `/animal` page again, their selection is lost.  **How do I retain the value that they chose?**

All the examples I have looked at show the value being saved in the `animal` model, but in Ember Inspector on the 'Data' tab for 'animal', it shows all 5 different animals retrieved from the API call.  **Should I have a second model?**

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: do you have a animal controller? where do you "save" selectedValue, or what do you have instead of '???'?

Comment: No I do not have an animal controller.  I'm not sure what to put instead of '???'

Comment: Also in step 2 of the questionnaire, I want to ensure they chose an option in step 1.

Comment: Hi Alan, this question is quite tricky to answer on SO alone, can you go by the [Ember Slack group](https://ember-community-slackin.herokuapp.com/)?